# Null pointer exception while returning cell value from excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, poi-hssf, hssf

I have the following code

private void execute_TestCase() throws Exception {

```
    int iTotalTestCases = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
    System.out.println("Total TC count" + iTotalTestCases);
    **formname=ExcelUtils.getCellData(13, 6, Constants.Sheet_TestCases);**
    System.out.println("F"+formname);

    for(int iTestcase=1;iTestcase<iTotalTestCases;iTestcase++){
        bResult = true;
        sTestCaseID = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestCases); 
        sRunMode = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_RunMode,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
        if (sRunMode.equals("Yes")){
            Log.startTestCase(sTestCaseID);
            iTestStep = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseID, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
            iTestLastStep = ExcelUtils.getTestStepsCount(Constants.Sheet_TestSteps, sTestCaseID, iTestStep);
            bResult=true;
            System.out.println("sTestCaseID"+ sTestCaseID);
            System.out.println("iTestStep"+ iTestStep);
            System.out.println("iTestLastStep"+ iTestLastStep);
            for (;iTestStep<iTestLastStep;iTestStep++){
                sActionKeyword = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_ActionKeyword,Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                sPageObject = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_PageObject, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                sData = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_DataSet, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                execute_Actions();
                if(bResult==false){
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                    Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);
                    break;
                    }                       
                }
            if(bResult==true){
            ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
            Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);   
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

formname=ExcelUtils.getCellData(13, 6, Constants.Sheet_TestCases). When calling the NullPointerException in getcelldata. But with same (13,6) pair it works fine at the bottom.
Find below the getCellData code

```
 public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName ) throws Exception{
                try{
                    System.out.println("sheet"+SheetName);
                    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                    System.out.println("Excelwsheet"+ExcelWSheet);
                    Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
                    System.out.println("test here2");
                    String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println("Celldata"+CellData);
                    return CellData;
                 }catch (Exception e){
                     System.out.println("Exception" + e);
                     Log.error("Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                     DriverScript.bResult = true;
                     return"";
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Sheet.getRow(int) Apache POI javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29)

> Returns - Row representing the rownumber or null if its not defined on the sheet

You therefore need to change this line with no null checking:

```
Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
```

For something more like this, which does check + handle the row (or cell!) being null:

```
 Row row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
 if (row == null) {
    // Handle empty row
    return "";
 }
 Cell cell = row.getCell(ColNum, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
 if (cell == null) {
    // Handle empty cell
    return "";
 }
```

You might also want to handle cells which contain things other than strings, and a few other common problems too... Have a read through the [Apache POI Spreadsheet docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) to learn what you need to be doing!